# JSON ARRAY from Key Value Pair in Cosmos

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We are receive a csv file containing invoice information, which we store in Cosmos as a key value pair. as below

Document -1

```json
{
        "InvoiceNumber": "12345",
        "InvoiceLineAmount": "10.21",
        "InvoiceId": 1,
        "AccountingDate": "2023/05/09",
        "SupplierNumber": "7777",
        "SupplierSite": "TESTSUPPLIER"       
    }
```

Document-2

```json
 {
        "InvoiceNumber": "12345",
        "InvoiceLineAmount": "15.05",
        "InvoiceId": 2,
        "AccountingDate": "2023/03/09",
        "SupplierNumber": "6666",
        "SupplierSite": "TESTSUPPLIER"
        
    }
```

Requirement to create JSON array containing one invoice with several invoice line items and store into other cosmos container as below. Any suggestion please.

```json
{
    "InvoiceNumber": "12345",
    "InvoiceLineDeatils": [
        {
            "InvoiceLineAmount": "10.21",
            "InvoiceId": 1,
            "AccountingDate": "2023/05/09",
            "SupplierNumber": "7777",
            "SupplierSite": "TESTSUPPLIER" 
        },
        {
            "InvoiceLineAmount": "15.05",
            "InvoiceId": 2,
            "AccountingDate": "2023/03/09",
            "SupplierNumber": "6666",
            "SupplierSite": "TESTSUPPLIER"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please edit to show your work (e.g. the query you tried), expected vs actual behavior, etc. As written, you only showed some data and expected result, but you didn't show any effort of your own.

Comment: Also, you've introduced an *anti-pattern* - storing an unbounded array within a single document.

Comment: If the array is not unbounded you might be able to use Patch operation using Add. But you'll need to maintain an array index and increment each time so that successive items get appended to the array. If you cannot do this in memory you will have to first read the document, count the members, then increment before doing a patch. More details here, https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update#supported-operations

Comment: @abdul As David mentioned, the input which you have provided here is an anti-pattern. How are you even being able to store this data in COSMOS DB document? Can you please share your actual input sample?

Comment: I appreciate all of your responses. Details of the sample document have been modified above. 
If my explanation was unclear, I apologise. 
I'm loading a CSV file into Cosmos container-1 using an ADF copy activity, so Document 1 and Document 2 are in container-1. 
The next step is to combine these two documents into a single document (one invoice number with different line details) and store it in a different cosmos container.